# Add Text Search to Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying out the open source Kendo Grid for the first time.  I have the basic grid up and running just fine, but now I need to add a search feature, with a search on first and last names.  I am trying to do it in ajax but I am stuck on an error:

Error:  Cannot call method 'read' of undefined

my code:

```
        <div id="search-index">
                <div class="editor-field">   
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("FirstName")

                    <label style = "margin-left: 15px;">Last Name:</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("LastName", "", new { style = "margin-right: 15px;" })
                </div>            
                <div id="search-controls-index">
                      <input type="button" id="searchbtn" class="skbutton" value="Search" />
                      <input type="button" id="addPersonbtn" class="skbutton" value="Add New Person" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddPerson", "Person")'"/>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div id="index-grid"></div>        
   </div>



    $(document).ready(function () {


        var grid = $('#index-grid').kendoGrid({
            height: 370,
            sortable: true,
            scrollable: true,
            pageable: true,
            dataSource: {
                        pageSize: 8,  
                        transport: {
                                    read: "/Home/GetPeople",
                                    dataType:"json"
                                    }
                        },
            columns: [
                                { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name" },
                                { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
                                { field: "Gender", title: "Gender" },
                                { field: "DOB", title: "Date of Birth", template: '#= kendo.toString(new Date(parseInt(DOB.substring(6))), "MM/dd/yyyy") #' },
                                { field: "IsStudent", title: "Is a Student?" }]
        });


        $("#searchbtn").on('click', function () {
            var fsname = $("#FirstName").val();
            var ltname = $("#LastName").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/GetPeople")',
                data: { fname: fsname, lname: ltname },
                success: function (data) {
                    grid.dataSource.read();
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#index-grid").html("An error occured while trying to retieve your data.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Should matter, but here is my controller (using asp MVC 3):

```
    public JsonResult GetPeople(string fname, string lname)
    {
        if (((fname == "") && (lname == "")) || ((fname == null) && (lname == null)))
       {
                var peopleList = repo.GetPeople();

                return Json(peopleList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
        else
        {
            var personResult = repo.GetSearchResult(fname, lname);

            return Json(personResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it make the initial page load call to GetPeople?

Comment: FYI you can use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(fname)` to check for null, empty string or whitespace. No need to do all those checks you're doing manually.. very messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$("#grid").kendoGrid()` returns a jQuery object which doesn't have a `dataSource` field. Here is how to get a reference to the client-side object: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/grid/overview#accessing-an-existing-grid

Comment: I am probably missing something, but it seems to me I am already following that.  The variable 'grid' is of the whole grid, with datasource, etc.  I am very new to programming in general, so it is possible I am going about this all wrong anyway.  I have searched for a couple days and have not found a single reference to anyone combining a text search with a Kendo grid.  Do you know of any references to it?

Comment: Did you check the help article that I've sent? It shows how to get a reference to the grid client-side object.

Comment: Yes but I still can't figure out how to filter my grid with a textbox search.  I'm still pretty new to programming, and I know I would eventually figure it out, but I have already spent 6 hours on this and need to move on.  Thank you for your time.